# how to force user to input exactly 8 characters into string

Tags: c++, string, delimiter, getline

how can I limit a user to input 8 characters into string?
can something like this work?

```
string MyString;
getline(std::cin, MyString, 8);
```

or maybe there is a different idea to accomplish it

thanks in advance

**clarification:**
I want to enable the user to input **up to** 8 characters in the string, but he may enter less.

Comment: `istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);` So the last parameter is a delimiter, not the number of char to get.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop..

```
while (MyString.length() != 8) {
  std::cout << "Enter exactly 8 characters:";
  getline(std::cin, MyString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its hard to think this will help considering my experience (1mnth!)
at codecademy.com in the "Python" language one might say something like:

```
my_string = "jackie"
len(my_string)

#would print 5

if my_string is <= .....  # if my string is greater or equal to print the following
    print "name is too long "
```

Hope that generated something other than disgust

sincerely dedicated noobie

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between requesting 8 characters from the User and preventing the User from entering more than 8.

**Requesting 8 from User**
You can request 8 characters from the User, but the User is allowed to enter as many characters as the User wants until a newline character is entered.  This is the behavior of the standard console input.

The console has buffered the all the characters.  Depending on the extraction method, you will be extracting 8 characters from the input buffer into your variable.  The remaining characters are still in the buffer.

**Preventing User from entering more than 8**
This is typically used in entering passwords.  The standard C++ input facilities cannot help here.

You will need platform specific control of the input source.  You will need to read each character, test for a newline and optionally echo back either the character, a uniform character like '*', or not display any characters.

Since it is platform specific, look up the API for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string str;
    bool cStr = true; //check string
    while (cStr){
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        if (str.size() <= 8) cStr = false;
    }
}
```

You can add a bool object to test your string using an if-statement. If the string size is less than or equal to 8, it will then advert the bool statement to false allowing the exit of the while loop.